# Magento on live site forwarding to localhost!

Tags: localhost, installer

i have a problem with the re-setup magento. 
i download back-up site on Cpanel. and export DB.
i want setup to localhost.
But it just redirects to the live site. How it works on localhost.
I've edited the content in /app/etc/local.xml and romove var/cache
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%base_url%'
```

to find values and change column value to **http://localhost/**

Comment: i know that. but tabel core_config_data is empty

Comment: Try repairing Or Re-importing the DB , core_config_data should not be empty

Comment: impossible that after DB export core_config_data table is empty, dump that table change what I said and it must work.

Comment: exactly. the import was not successful

Answer (score 1):

If you use windows edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc Host file and add your domain name redirected to localhost.

```
127.0.0.1       yourdomain.com
```

In linux use **vim /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com
```

Now all calls from your computer to yourdomain.com would be resolved back to your computer.